# storing result of array.foreach inside another array

Tags: javascript

I have a sample of code like this :

```js
  const iam = ['dd', 'aaa', 'cc'];
    async function bigTest() {
      async function details() {
        const arr = [];
        const files = [];
        iam.forEach(async (i) => {
          arr.push({
            name: 'test',
          });
    
          files.push(arr);
          return files;
        });
      }
    
      const result = await details();
      console.log(result);
    }
    bigTest();
```

and i want to store the final result of `arr` in the array `files` but it returns undefined

Inside the loop, it returns the array but outside the details function, it return undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the function `map`.

As you need the `async` declaration, the array from the `map` function contains Promises, so you need to resolve them as follow:

```
Promise.all(files);
```

```js
const iam = ['dd', 'aaa', 'cc'];
async function bigTest() {
  async function details() {
    const files = iam.map(async(name) => {
      return { name };
    });

    return Promise.all(files);
  }

  const result = await details();
  console.log(result);
}

bigTest();
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i'm working a code that's working in the same structure and i'm in need of that await so i just posted a similar example instead of the whole code

Comment: @brxnzaz do you need the async declaration here `iam.forEach(async (i) => {...}`?

Comment: yes i need it in there as well because i'm doing a treatment on each element by calling a function that takes time to return a result

Comment: i totally forgot about promise.all. thank you, it worked for me now

Comment: your exemple worked fine for me but when i tried it on my own code which consist of pushing data inside the array.map loop, i get as an output [ 1, 2, 3 ]

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you really want to do is use the return outside of the forEach()

```js
  const iam = ['dd', 'aaa', 'cc'];
    async function bigTest() {
      async function details() {
        const arr = [];
        const files = [];
        iam.forEach(async (i) => {
          arr.push({
            name: 'test',
          });
    
          files.push(arr);
        });
        return files;
      }
    
      const result = await details();
      console.log(result);
    }
    bigTest();
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.forEach always returns undefined. You are looking for Array.map

Comment: i tried it with map as well, the only difference is in that case it returns [ [ Promise { undefined },

Answer (score 0):

None of this code should have to be asynchronous. Get rid of all of the async/awaits and you should be fine.

Comment: i'm working a code that's working in the same structure and i'm in need of that await so i just posted a similar example instead of the whole code